# Are utm_content values available with Multi-Channel Funnel Reports?

Tags: google-analytics

I wonder if the `utm_content`parameter is available in any of the muti-channel funnel reports?

I have several cmapaigns subdivided by values for `utm_content`. Looking at the *Top Conversion Path* and *Assited Conversion Path* report I'd like to figure out how these contents contributed to conversions individually.

If this is not possible, how else would I go about this? Am I forced to use `utm_campaign` or `utm_keyword` instead?

Answer (score 1):

You can make a new set of channel definitions, and tailor those to match how you tag. You can do this at view level in the admin panel. Rather than start from scratch it's easier to copy the existing set of definitions and edit them.

Or you can do it from a report that uses channel grouping, above the table you'll see a drop-down menu called Channel Groupings and you make a new one or copy and edit an existing one.